# Regex extracting image links

Tags: java, regex

I've got the following Regular Expression to extract links out of an HTML document, using java.util.regex

```html
 <a\s.*?href=([^ >]+).*?<img\s.*?src=([^ ]+)(.*?>.*?<\/a>)
```

and suspect it to match the last link in this markup.

```html
<font size="4">Mail : </font><a href="mailto:c.bantz@pgt-gmbh.com"><u><font size="4" color="#0000ff">s.weber@pgt-gmbh.com</font></u></a><br />
<br />
<font size="4">Internet : </font><a href="http://www.pgt-gmbh.com/"><u><font size="4" color="#0000ff">http://www.pgt-gmbh.com</font></u></a><font size="4"> </font><br />
<br />
<br />
<font size="4"> </font><a class="domino-attachment-link" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center" href="/_dv/_dv/documents_DE.nsf/0/7fadd8be280a2e34c1257dfd00307098/$FILE/Anfrage.pdf" title="Anfrage.pdf"><img src="/_dv/_dv/documents_DE.nsf/0/7fadd8be280a2e34c1257dfd00307098/f_Text/0.5F66?OpenElement&FieldElemFormat=gif" width="32" height="32" alt="Anfrage.pdf" border="0" /> - Anfrage.pdf</a>
```

But it doesn't match the link but does something like a greedy search, starting with the mailto: and ending with the last link. The same expression works fine with the regex tester within http://regex101.com.

Any hints?

Comment: escape the backslash one more time.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a HTML parser?

Comment: if escaping was the problem, java would not compile. In fact even eclipse is able to find the regex correctly, but java is not.

Comment: Mandatory link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Escaping the backslashes is not the problem. I just removed them to provide a solution which is testable within the RegEx tester. @stefanA How did you test it within eclipse?

Comment: put your content into a textfile and use Ctrl-F (with regex-checkbox on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would not occur if newlines are at the end of the text lines.

**Now I have an explanation:** The `<a href="mailto` is matched by the regular expression `<a\s.*?href=([^ >]+)`. The following `.*?` will match any character sequence (without line breaks) until it finds `<img...`. And it does exactly this (in absence of line breaks).

**Example** (one with and one without newlines):

```
private static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile("<a\\s.*?href=([^ >]+).*?<img\\s.*?src=([^ ]+)(.*?>.*?<\\/a>)");
private static final String TEXT = "<font size=\"4\">Mail              : </font><a href=\"mailto:c.bantz@pgt-gmbh.com\"><u><font size=\"4\" color=\"#0000ff\">s.weber@pgt-gmbh.com</font></u></a><br />"
    + "<br />"
    + "<font size=\"4\">Internet        : </font><a href=\"http://www.pgt-gmbh.com/\"><u><font size=\"4\" color=\"#0000ff\">http://www.pgt-gmbh.com</font></u></a><font size=\"4\"> </font><br />"
    + "<br />"
    + "<br />"
    + "<font size=\"4\"> </font><a class=\"domino-attachment-link\" style=\"display: inline-block; text-align: center\" href=\"/_dv/_dv/documents_DE.nsf/0/7fadd8be280a2e34c1257dfd00307098/$FILE/Anfrage.pdf\" title=\"Anfrage.pdf\"><img src=\"/_dv/_dv/documents_DE.nsf/0/7fadd8be280a2e34c1257dfd00307098/f_Text/0.5F66?OpenElement&FieldElemFormat=gif\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" alt=\"Anfrage.pdf\" border=\"0\" /> - Anfrage.pdf</a>";
private static final String NEWLINE_TEXT = "<font size=\"4\">Mail              : </font><a href=\"mailto:c.bantz@pgt-gmbh.com\"><u><font size=\"4\" color=\"#0000ff\">s.weber@pgt-gmbh.com</font></u></a><br />\n"
    + "<br />\n"
    + "<font size=\"4\">Internet        : </font><a href=\"http://www.pgt-gmbh.com/\"><u><font size=\"4\" color=\"#0000ff\">http://www.pgt-gmbh.com</font></u></a><font size=\"4\"> </font><br />\n"
    + "<br />\n"
    + "<br />\n"
    + "<font size=\"4\"> </font><a class=\"domino-attachment-link\" style=\"display: inline-block; text-align: center\" href=\"/_dv/_dv/documents_DE.nsf/0/7fadd8be280a2e34c1257dfd00307098/$FILE/Anfrage.pdf\" title=\"Anfrage.pdf\"><img src=\"/_dv/_dv/documents_DE.nsf/0/7fadd8be280a2e34c1257dfd00307098/f_Text/0.5F66?OpenElement&FieldElemFormat=gif\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" alt=\"Anfrage.pdf\" border=\"0\" /> - Anfrage.pdf</a>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matcher m = P.matcher(TEXT);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
    m = P.matcher(NEWLINE_TEXT);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

`<a href="mailto:c.bantz@pgt-gmbh.com">...` without newlines

`<a class="domino-attachment-link"...` with newlines

**A better pattern**

`<a\s[^>]*?href=([^>]+)><img\s.*?src=([^ ]+)(.*?>.*?<\/a>)`

The problem with HTML and regex is that the upper pattern matches only a specific situation, if some markup is between `<a...>` and `<img...>` then it would fail. Surely this could be fixed, but the expression gets more and more incomprehensible.

So: If you want to do this extraction issues for more than one link, you should switch to an HTML-Parser (although finding the best is a science of its own).

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear. I've just found out, there is `Pattern.DOTALL` which will even match including linebreaks. Have you also a tip, how I can change the pattern so that it only includes links with an `<img` tag present?

Comment: I just edited my answer and added a working pattern. But extracting html with regular expressions is really malicious. This pattern might work in one case and another special case would fail. Therefore a html parser is the best choice.